# No EntitySet Created

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am learning LINQ to SQL.I created 2 tables Project and TimeLogs.TimeLog has projectid as foreign key.But, when I drag these 2 tables in designer, the classes generated do not reflect this relationship in the form of entityset.

regards

Comment: Does it represent any relationship? Or just nothing?

Comment: No relationship is represented.The timetracker just has projectid as an int property

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your Project table doesn't have a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if the timelog table doesn't have its foreign key relationship with the project table formally defined as a foreign key constraint in the database.